# Professor Roman loves to teach unorthodox Chemistry

Tags: word, chemistry

His famous phrase in class was “ Elementary Watson”.

Given:

$IRON$  = $5$ - $4$

$M$   =    $6$  -  $9$

Find the Missing Element M.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Prof. Roman of the Chemistry dept. says

> 5 - 4 = five - IV → Fe, the symbol for iron.

so if M = 6 - 9 then

> 6 - 9 = six - IX → S, the symbol for **sulphur**.

Comment: @Uvc - Roman might write the two elements before this answer as $6 - 10$ and $\pi - 1$ :P

Comment: Good one..we can be apprentices to Prof. Roman to learn his craft further.